# How to set the z-index of a child element so that it does not climb onto the parent element

Tags: html, css

Good afternoon, I ran into such a problem.
I have blocks of text that are connected by lines that are in the block itself and are positioned using position absolute.
I need the blocks to always be on top of these lines, but the z-index of the line works only on adjacent blocks, but not on the parent.
Below is the markup and styles.

```
          <!-- how box -->
          <div class="how__box">

            <div class="how__box__text">
              Обсуждение проекта <br>
              и заполнение брифа
            </div>

            <img class="how__box__img" src="img/how/how-penguin-1.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

            <!-- This is my line -->
            <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-1" src="img/how/how-line-1.svg" alt="arrow-right">

          </div>
```

```
.how__box
  position: relative
  min-height: 170px
  margin-bottom: 150px
  padding: 30px 40px
  display: flex
  justify-content: start
  align-items: center
  background-color: #fff
  border-radius: 50px
  opacity: .99
  z-index: 1
  &:nth-child(even)
    margin-left: auto
    .how__box__text
      margin-right: 0px

.how__box__arrow
  position: absolute
  height: 300px
  bottom: -140%
  z-index: -1
```

[image]

Comment: So, there are two options (in my opinion): **1**: Split text box and arrow from one div (with class how__box) or **2**: make different z-indexes: z-index: 1 to bottom div, z-index: 2 to middle div and z-index: 3 to top div

Comment: Unfortunately the second option didn't work.

I can't implement the first option, since my lines are positioned absolutely for this box.

Comment: And could you please share a bigger example of your code (best in form oc execitible code snippet) or link to your site?

Comment: https://github.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio master branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I FOUND ANOTHER SOLUTION! HOORAY!**

Original code:

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat /*Only for output to be better visible*/
}

.how {
  margin-top: 150px
}

.how__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
}

.how__box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  opacity: .99;
  z-index: 10;
}

.how__box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.how__box__text {
  margin-right: 0px
}

.how__box--last {
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.how__box__text {
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 43px;
  z-index: 9
}

.how__box__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: -120%;
  z-index: 1
}

.how__box__arrow-1 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-2 {
  right: 40%
}

.how__box__arrow-3 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-4 {
  right: 40%
}

.how__box__arrow-5 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-6 {
  bottom: -110% right: 40%
}


/* ************** Media ************** */

@media screen and ( max-width: 1060px) {
  .how__box__text {
    font-size: 30px
  }
  .how__box__img {
    width: 120px
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="how">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="section__title how__title">Как мы работаем</div>

    <div class="how__wrapper">

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Обсуждение проекта <br> и заполнение брифа
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-1.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <!-- This is my line -->
        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-1" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-1.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Анализ конкурентов <br> и целевой аудитории ниши
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-2" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-2.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Создание прототипа <br> будущего сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-2.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-3" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-3.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Создание адаптивного <br> дизайна страницы сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-4" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-4.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Утверждение дизайна <br> и внесение поправок
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-3.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-5" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-5.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Адаптивная верстка сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-6" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-6.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box how__box--last">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Посадка сайта <br> на домен и хостинг
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

1. Remove opacity 0.99 from .how__box
2. Add style `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to .how__box
3. Add style `transform: translateZ(-10px)` to .how__box__arrow

This makes move arrow 10px below parent div element:

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat/* Only for output to be better visible */
}

.how {
  margin-top: 150px
}

.how__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
}

.how__box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 170px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  padding: 30px 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  /*opacity: .99;*/ /* Removed opacity */
  z-index: 10;
  
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* New */
}

.how__box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.how__box__text {
  margin-right: 0px
}

.how__box--last {
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

.how__box__text {
  margin-right: 70px;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 43px;
  z-index: 9
}

.how__box__arrow {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  bottom: -120%;
  z-index: 1;
  
  transform: translateZ(-10px); /* NEW */
}

.how__box__arrow-1 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-2 {
  right: 40%
}

.how__box__arrow-3 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-4 {
  right: 40%
}

.how__box__arrow-5 {
  left: 80%
}

.how__box__arrow-6 {
  bottom: -110% right: 40%
}


/* ************** Media ************** */

@media screen and ( max-width: 1060px) {
  .how__box__text {
    font-size: 30px
  }
  .how__box__img {
    width: 120px
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="how">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="section__title how__title">Как мы работаем</div>

    <div class="how__wrapper">

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Обсуждение проекта <br> и заполнение брифа
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-1.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <!-- This is my line -->
        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-1" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-1.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Анализ конкурентов <br> и целевой аудитории ниши
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-2" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-2.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Создание прототипа <br> будущего сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-2.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-3" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-3.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Создание адаптивного <br> дизайна страницы сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-4" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-4.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Утверждение дизайна <br> и внесение поправок
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__img" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-penguin-3.svg" alt="how-penguin-1">

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-5" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-5.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Адаптивная верстка сайта
        </div>

        <img class="how__box__arrow how__box__arrow-6" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sparkkkd/dashportfolio/master/src/img/how/how-line-6.svg" alt="arrow-right">

      </div>

      <!-- how box -->
      <div class="how__box how__box--last">

        <div class="how__box__text">
          Посадка сайта <br> на домен и хостинг
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Hope it will finally work! :)

Comment: I did everything as you advised, but unfortunately the behavior of the lines has not changed.
I noticed that the lines do not overlap the text in the box, but overlap the box itself. Screenshot https://imgur.com/a/mxlcEBk

Comment: And in my second snippet - there is the same issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.
The problem is that the lines, as you can see in the screenshot, are superimposed on top of the box itself, in which they are located, but at the same time they do not overlap with the block with the text, which is also in this box.
I need to do something like that the z-index for the line is triggered on its parent element, that is, on the main box itself

Comment: No, I think I'll rewrite the whole structure and try to find another way out

Comment: Ur last solution is great, it work! Thank u bro!